# Nested attributes (Paperclip) validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-forms

I'm working on a nested form where a user when creating a Screen should also attached an image (a separate model called Screenshot). I'm trying to validate the presence of the attachment before saving the new Screen to the db. I tried to validate the presence of the attachment in the Screenshot model, but that only precent Screenshot to be saved, while it still creates a Screen.

Here's my models:

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project
  has_many :screenshots

  validates :name, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :screenshots

  validates_presence_of :screenshots 

end


class Screenshot < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :screen

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

end
```

here's my controller:

```
def create
    @screen = Screen.create(screen_params)
    if @screen.save
      flash[:notice] = "A new screen has been added to this project"
      redirect_to [@screen.project]
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

And lastly here's my form:

```
<%= form_for ([@project, @screen]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @screen.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@screen.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this screen from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @screen.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :project_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :screenshots, @screen.screenshots.build do |s| %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :screen_id, :value => @screen.id %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :version, :value => "1" %>
    <%= s.label :image %><br>
    <%= s.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any help to this noob is greatly appreciated.

Comment: validates_presence_of :image should be in Screenshot model.  Also make sure that your nested form is working. Try saving and see if image gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Several things for you:

**Form**
You shouldn't build new objects in the form itself. That needs to happen in the controller's `new` function

```
 <%= f.fields_for :screenshots do |s| %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :screen_id, :value => @screen.id %>
    <%= s.hidden_field :version, :value => "1" %>
    <%= s.label :image %><br>
    <%= s.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
```

You can declare them like this:

```
def new
    @screen = Screen.new
    @screen.screenshots.build
    #any more build declarations go here
end
```

**Verification**
I believe you should put the verification into the screnshots model, as the nested parameters are passed directly to the corresponding model. I'm not sure on that though.

In the screenshots model, I would put the `validates_presence_of :screenshots`, with the name as your Paperclip attachment's name

Comment: Joe, thanks for your answer. My problem with adding the build new object in the controller is that following your example the field doesn't appear in my rendered form. Any idea on why?

Comment: To me, it looks like its ([@ project, @ screen]) which might be the problem. Are you displaying this view in a nested resource of @project by any chance? I just don't see any reference to @ project in your controller, and I feel that Rails will be getting confused because of this. From your code, I would just use <%= form_for @ screen; but there is going to be more than just that

Comment: Yes, the form is pulled into the show view of @project. Basically in the @ project show I have a list of all the screens of that project and I also have a form to add new ones.